# If union is disconnected and open then the sets are open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

> Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, if $A \cup B$ is disconnected and open, then is it necessary that both $A$ and $B $ are open?

I feel that it is true,  as disconnectedness and openness together restrict from taking semi-open/closed sets here, but don't know how to prove.

Comment: Let $A$ be the union of two disjoint open disks and let $B$ be the (non-open) set consisting of a single point inside of one of them.  (I have a feeling you haven't phrased your question just right.)

Comment: Above $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Comment: Right, and that's what I gave you.

Comment: yeah, I got that. Thanx

Comment: If we have an additional condition that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint then does it still hold?

Comment: see the answer below from Aweygan.  Note that their $A$ and $B$ are in fact disjoint.

Answer (score 3):

No.  Let 
$$X=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:x>1\}\cup\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:x<-1\}.$$
  Then $X$ is open and disconnected.  Now let 
$$A=X\cap\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:y\geq 0\},$$
$$B=X\cap\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:y<0\}.$$
  Then $X=A\cup B$, but $A$ is not open.